# What is CP1 in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI?

Tags: sql-server

I was wondering what the "CP1" means in the collation "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI".

This should be the codepage, but doesn't exist a codepage 1 (for ex. I know it exists a CP850, but never heard about a CP1).

Comment: I presume the 1 is for "Windows Latin 1"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`CP1` denotes code page 1252 as described in the [SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx).  You can also use the query below to identify the collation code page.

```
SELECT name, COLLATIONPROPERTY(name, 'CodePage') AS CodePage
FROM fn_helpcollations()
ORDER BY name;
```